# jquery toggle is toggling twice

Tags: jquery

I have a div element containing a few other divs with an id of `#popup_inner_wrapper`.

When I use the JS console in chrome:

```
$('#popup_inner_wrapper').toggle("fast");
```

It hides the div, but then shows it again.

If I hide the div at page load with css, then toggle it from the console the div will show. If I then toggle again from the console it will hide and show again in one action.

What could be causing this behavior?

**EDIT:**

HTML is similar to the code below. In response to it being a double binding issue: there are no events bound anywhere: I am calling toggle form the console and seeing the 'fired twice behavior'...

```
<div class="popup_outer_wrapper">
   <a href="#" id="toggle_link">Show/hide</a>  # nothing is bound to this link atm!
   <div id="popup_inner_wrapper">
     <div class="popup_body">
       contents..
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems i might be encountering the same problem as described here: [JQuery Toggle not working as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232244/jquery-toggle-not-working-as-it-should). The problem being some of those divs are positioned absolute. For some reason `.toggle()` will not work with absolute positioned divs.

Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Could you please post your HTML as well.

Comment: You've double initialized, or double bound to something. Include a link please.

Comment: your html and javascript will help a lot

Comment: Thanks Sinetheta.  You nailed it for me.  I was setting the click event every time my ajax returned something rather than once for the entire page.  My fix was to use 
$(".ui-icon").live("click",function(){
    // set toggle event in here
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i might be encountering the same problem as described here: [JQuery Toggle not working as it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232244/jquery-toggle-not-working-as-it-should). The problem being some of those divs are positioned absolute. For some reason .toggle() will not work with absolute positioned divs.