# Bootstrap Modal Toggle event happening twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I have an `asp:DataList`.  Each item in the list has a Delete button that will pop up a confirmation modal.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlKeywords" runat="server" 
    RepeatLayout="Table" CssClass="table table-striped">
    <ItemTemplate>
    ...
        <div class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#modalDeleteWarning" data-keyword-id="<%# Eval("keywordId") %>"
            data-keyword-name="<%# Eval("keyword") %>">
        </div>
    ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<div id="modalDeleteWarning" class="modal fade">
    ...
</div>
```

For some reason the event fires twice, so it toggles on and off again immediately.

I tried looking at `$._data(btn_object_reference, "events")` to see if the click event handler was attached twice, but that returns `undefined`.

Not surprisingly, it works just fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywam1zd7/).

I looked at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232244/jquery-toggle-not-working-as-it-should), but none of the parent elements are `position: absolute`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14873109/twitter-bootstrap-modal-multiple-event-firing) suggests that AJAX might be the issue, and I do have this `DataList` in an `UpdatePanel`, but removing the UpdatePanel does not fix the issue.

I also tried removing the DataList, and just using a button on its own with contrived values, but I get the same behavior.

I don't know how to debug further.  Is there a way to see if the click event is being fired on multiple elements or something?

I'm javascript-proficient, but not an expert by any means, so I'm sure there are a lot of things I haven't checked yet.

Comment: Not sure this will do anything, but you're using a div as a button. Why not switch the trigger to a button? You could also add `role="dialog"` to your `.modal` which sometimes helps.

Comment: I had already tried the button thing.  Adding the role didn't work either.  =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I was loading both bootstrap.js v3.3.0 and bootstrap.js v3.3.1 onto the same page.  That'll do it.